# Event navigation keys window CE?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-5.0

I'm a newbie in Window mobile development.

I'm trying to develop an application running on window CE 5.0.

The device uses key navigation.

How do I write an event for Navigation keys.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an emulator with the WM5 SDK that you can use to view the designer under Visual Studio.

Here is the easy way:  In the designer, just double-click one of the buttons to let Visual Studio wire everything up for you.